# mysql insert statement is inserting a blank row instead of the data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add new users to my database. For some reason while using the same exact statement in two different scripts and trying to debug, mysql inserts a blank row instead of the actual data if I try to run the query from the php script in which I need it to run from.

On the other hand, when I try to run that exact query in from a random php script, passing the same exact variables (using session variables) to the database, it inserts the data into the database as it should with no problems. I have not idea how to fix such a problem and have been trying for quite a while now. I would greatly appreciate any advice on what I could do to fix this problem.

```
$usr_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$usr_company_name = $_SESSION['compame'];
$usr_city = $_SESSION['city'];
$usr_state = $_SESSION['state'];
$usr_phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
$usr_password = $_SESSION['password'];
$usr_first = $_SESSION['first'];
$usr_last = $_SESSION['last'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, email, compname, city, state, phone, password, first, last)
        VALUES('','$usr_email','$usr_company_name','$usr_city','$usr_state','$usr_phone','$usr_password','$usr_first','$usr_last')",$conn);
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of that PHP file?

Comment: do a var_dump() on the $_SESSION just before you do the insert - I bet there is no data in the $_SESSION for some reason

Comment: @TheShiftExchange thanks for the reply. The same exact variables are created on two different scripts, using the same exact session variables, and one inserts the actual session variable data, one doesnt... if the session variables didn't contain anything, I wouldn't be able to store anything regardless of where I am running the query from.

Comment: Additional tip: Assuming your `id` field is an auto-incremented INT, you don't need to include it in the insert statement. Take it out of both the column specifications as well as the value specifications.

Comment: As there is nothing wrong in the provided code and you say that you run session_start() we can only assume that the session array is empty. Is the session values collected from a database? Maybe that query fails for some reason, add or die(mysqlerror()) at the end of all queries during production so you can see if something fails.

Comment: @Zane Bien after removing the 'id' fields, its not inserting anything, no blank row, no data row... thanks for the tip though;)

Comment: @MHZ, leave the id fields out still, but do this after you execute the query: `echo mysql_error($conn);` and tell us what it says, if it says anything.

Comment: :/ still cant find the problem, printed out all session variables, so all of them are set correctly, they aren't empty... ran 'or die(mysqlerror()) and nothing printed out... no errors...

Comment: If I insert string values, it inserts just fine, if I insert the variables that I set to the $_SESSION variables that I printed out and verified that they contained the data I need, it adds an empty row, I cannot come up with a logical explanation for this!! gr....

Comment: @MHZ, Have you tried to print the query itself? And run that query in the MYSQL query?

Comment: Suggestion: replace just `$usr_last` with a literal string and run the script. If you get a new row with all columns blank except for `last`, then the problem is that it's treating the other variables as blank. If you get a new row with _all_ columns blank, then something is just plain breaking your query.

Comment: @octern thanks for the reply, thats exactly what I said I did, I inserted all string literals in the query and ran the query and it added a new row with all the values correctly. When I replace those string literals with variables I actually need (and I printed out those session variables within the same script to make sure they aren't empty), then it inserts an ALL blank row:/

Comment: It's not exactly the same -- I suggested leaving all the variables in place and just inserting a literal string for the last column. That will allow you to find out whether one of the other variables you are including is breaking your query (in which case you might get an all-blank row even though the last column was specified literally), or whether they're merely being treated as empty.

Comment: I followed your advice, changing the last column to a literal inserts the last column to the database, however, all other columns remain empty.